# How to initialize booleans?

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to write a boolean condition for genre fiction or non fiction for my program. However there is something wrong?

For the instance variable:

```
private boolean fiction, nonFiction;
```

or

```
private boolean Genre;
```

that compiles fine, but I don't know how to initialise this?

```
Genre = "";
```

No idea, I am a beginner to Java still learning.

Also I need to create a method which will give me true or false depending the input, can pointers be given so I can note how to create this method?

Comment: `private boolean Genre = false;` or `private boolean Genre = true;`

Comment: a boolean expression takes either `true` or `false` as a value.

Comment: `""` is the empty string, not false.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to initialise this?

```
boolean fiction = true;
```

There is no need to initialize boolean member to false, because [that's its default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#Default%20Values), so this is enough:

```
boolean fiction; // fiction is initialized automatically to false
```

> also I need to create a method which will give me true or false depending the input, can pointers be given so I can note how to create this method?

```
boolean function(Object input) {
    if (something) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what about for false? do i again have to put

private boolean nonFiction = false;

below that

Comment: @S2095b No, you have one variable named `finction`. It can take two values: true or false, depending what you assign to it.

Comment: Can the object input be String fiction so when that's inserted it will display true if not it will be false?

Answer (score 1):

Java instance variables are automatically initialized either 0 (or equivalent) for numbers, null for objects, or false for booleans.  So you don't need to explicitly do it.  But you can, but you must provide something valid.  eg.:

```
private boolean Genre = false;
```

You need to read up more in order to create functions, but the general signature should look like

```
<access qualifier> <return type> <method name>(parmeters ..){
    // logic here
    return <something with return type>;
}

eg.:

public boolean myFunction(int someparameter, int someotherparameter){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what i don't done understand is, does it have to be false by default? i mean your code above just simply means the outcome will be false? but what happens if someone inserts fiction that should be true?

Comment: Instance variables have an initial value provided by the runtime.  This is different from other languages to prevent errors of missing initializers (eg. C).  You cannot change system default value, but you can one to it.  Every time the object is instantiated, it will take on this value.  If you want the variable to be true, you have to explicitly declare it (eg. private boolean Genre = true;)